# SQL You have an error in your syntax - what is the syntactical error that I am having?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am using mysql workbench in order to run basic queries that should enable me to create a new table in my database. 
The code that I am trying to run is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airbnb.neighborhood;
CREATE TABLE airbnb.neighborhood (
    nbh_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nbh_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);
```

The error that I got is :

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c....
```

I cannot see any syntax error here, but it is giving me a red line under 'CREATE'.

It says

`) is not valid at this point. Expecting an identifier`

I checked other questions/SO articles with this message but they are all talking about solving different syntactical errors, so did not really help me.

Please assist, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `c....` this is the interesting bit

Comment: I like to put the commas at the start of the line, for precisely this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon at the end of the DROP TABLE line, i.e.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airbnb.neighborhood;
CREATE TABLE ....
```

This is because DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE are two separate SQL statements. The semicolon marks the end of the first statement and allows you to start the second.

Comment: Thank you Tom, and sorry, i just edited my post. I figured out that I was missing a semi colon. However, I am not sure why ")" is not expected at the end of my query in my edited post.

Comment: Solved! ```DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airbnb.neighborhood;
CREATE TABLE airbnb.neighborhood (
 nbh_id INT NOT NULL,
    nbh_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (nbh_id)
);```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE airbnb.neighborhood ( 
    nbh_id INT NOT NULL, 
    nbh_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (nbh_id) 
);
```